# How to compile shader with newest Effect Framework?

Tags: graphics, directx, directx-11, direct3d, direct3d11

I usually use the *Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)* which is deprecated. I download vs2015 which includes newest directx sdk and latest version FX11 on github. I don't know how to compile shader now.

- before I can compile shader like this

  ```
  ID3D10Blob *compiledShader = 0;
  ID3D10Blob *compilationMsgs = 0;
  result = D3DX11CompileFromFile("SolidColor.fx", 0, 0, 0, "fx_5_0", shaderFlags,
      0, 0, &compiledShader, &compilationMsgs, 0);

  if (compilationMsgs != 0)
  {
      MessageBox(0, (char*)compilationMsgs->GetBufferPointer(), 0, 0);
      compilationMsgs->Release();
      compilationMsgs = 0;
  }
  if (FAILED(result))
  {
      MessageBox(0, "error", 0, 0);
      return false;
  }

  result = D3DX11CreateEffectFromMemory(compiledShader->GetBufferPointer(), compiledShader->GetBufferSize(),
      0, m_pd3dDevice, &m_pFx);
  compiledShader->Release();

  if (FAILED(result))
  {
      MessageBox(0, "error", 0, 0);
      return false;
  }

  m_pTechnique = m_pFx->GetTechniqueByName("ColorTech");
  m_pFxWorldViewProj = m_pFx->GetVariableByName("gWorldViewProj")->AsMatrix();
  ```
- But now how to compile shader? use D3DX11CompileEffectFromFile or D3DX11CreateEffectFromFile? Please give sample code,thank you.

Comment: Be sure to check out the [wiki](https://github.com/Microsoft/FX11/wiki/Effects-11) for Effects 11 as well. It documents the functions to use that are a little different than the older MSDN docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know, it is so easy, just one function `D3DX11CompileEffectFromFile` is OK.

```
//compile shader
    ID3DBlob* errorBlob;
    DWORD shaderFlags = D3DCOMPILE_ENABLE_STRICTNESS;

#if defined _DEBUG || defined DEBUG
    shaderFlags = D3DCOMPILE_DEBUG;
#endif

    hr = D3DX11CompileEffectFromFile(L"color.fx", nullptr, D3D_COMPILE_STANDARD_FILE_INCLUDE, shaderFlags,
        0, m_pd3dDevice, &m_pFx, &errorBlob);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        MessageBox(nullptr, (LPCWSTR)errorBlob->GetBufferPointer(), L"error", MB_OK);
        return hr;
    }

    m_pTechnique = m_pFx->GetTechniqueByName("ColorTech");
    m_pFxWorldViewProj = m_pFx->GetVariableByName("gWorldViewProj")->AsMatrix();
```